# How do I fix camera weird mapping quirk?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, transforms, camera, uv-image-editor

I've run into a bit of a problem when trying to do some camera mapping.
This is what happened: 
[image: Volvo pls fix]

As you can see, the mapping is not working well. As far as I know, when you project to view, it should work every time, is there something that I'm missing? I have tried remaking the plane, and resizing it, it seems that the bigger it is, the less accurate it is. Please help me, I want to finish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I just realized that I had to subdivide the plane because if you don't have enough polygons, project from view will produce bad/inaccurate results.